# Tokenizing complex input

Tags: python, parsing, text, stream, tokenize

I'm attempting to tokenize the following input in Python:

```
text = 'This @example@ is "neither":/defn/neither complete[1] *nor* trite, *though _simple_*.'
```

I would like to produce something like the following while avoiding use of the regular expressions:

```
tokens = [
        ('text', 'This '),
        ('enter', 'code'),
            ('text', "example")
        ('exit', None),
        ('text', ' is '),
        ('enter', 'a'),
            ('text', "neither"),
            ('href', "/defn/neither"),
        ('exit', None),
        ('text', ' complete'),
        ('enter', 'footnote'),
            ('id', 1),
        ('exit', None),
        ('text', ' '),
        ('enter', 'strong'),
            ('text', 'nor'),
        ('exit', None),
        ('text', ' trite, '),
        ('enter', 'strong'),
                ('text', 'though '),
                ('enter', 'em'),
                    ('text', 'simple'),
                ('exit', None),
        ('exit', None),
        ('text', '.')
    ]
```

Pretend the above is being produced by a generator.  My [current implementation](https://github.com/marrow/marrow.texting/blob/develop/marrow/texting/engine.py#L301-359)  works, though the code is somewhat hideous and not easily extended to support links.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Updated to change the desired syntax from a complex nested list structure to a simple stream of tuples.  Indentation for us humans.  Formatting within the text of a link is OK.  Here is [a simple parser](https://gist.github.com/1162381#file_00_custom.py) that generates the lexing result I'm looking for, but still doesn't handle links or footnotes.

Comment: Interesting. Any particular reason why you'd want to avoid using regexes?

Comment: [`shlex`](http://docs.python.org/library/shlex.html) can help you and is available out of the box

Comment: @NullUserException Regexes are orders of magnitude slower than the current solution, and become complex when you begin to handle nested rulesets.

Comment: @JBernardo shlex is for parsing of shell-like whitespace-separated syntax; my problem domain doesn't come close, unless you can give me an example of use that alters the fundamental parser present in that module.

Comment: Regexes should not be slow. In my experience they often speed things up quite a bit, but you really have to know how to use them.

Comment: What you're posting is the AST of your input. You usually use a recursive descent parser to get this structure, not just a lexer. Is using a parser generator an option for you?

Comment: @Bart Kiers I wanted to avoid external dependancy; for most of this structure I have not needed it.  (See the example parser link at the end of the question.)

Comment: @Karl Knechtel Could you provide an example like my simple parser that produces the same output for comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, [here's a more complete parser](https://gist.github.com/1162381#file_01_complete.py) with sufficient extensibility to do whatever I may need in the future.  It only took three hours.  It's not terribly speedy, but generally the output of the class of parser I'm writing is heavily cached anyway.  Even with this tokenizer and parser in place, my full engine still clocks in at < 75% of the SLoC of the default python-textile renderer while remaining somewhat faster.  All without regular expressions.

Footnote parsing remains, but that's minor compared to link parsing.  The output (as of this posting) is:

```
tokens = [
    ('text', 'This '),
    ('enter', 'code'),
        ('text', 'example'),
    ('exit', None),
    ('text', ' is '),
    ('enter', 'a'),
        ('text', 'neither'),
        ('attr', ('href', '/defn/neither')),
    ('exit', None),
    ('text', ' complete[1] '),
    ('enter', 'strong'),
        ('text', 'nor'),
    ('exit', None),
    ('text', ' trite, '),
    ('enter', 'strong'),
        ('text', 'though '),
        ('enter', 'em'),
            ('text', 'simple'),
        ('exit', None),
    ('exit', None),
    ('text', '.')
]
```

Comment: As a quick note on the speed difference: the current state of the parser parses the project README (https://github.com/marrow/marrow.texting/blob/develop/README.textile) in 13.4 msec vs. Textile which takes 249 msec on the same document, generating nearly identical HTML markup.  Ouch!